# EOWEBBROWSER file data append

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using *EOWEBROWSER* to send some data and get back the data. This is the `C#` code I'm using on back-end:

```
void WebView_JSExtInvoke(object sender, JSExtInvokeArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.FunctionName)
        {
            case "applicationHeartbeat":
                heartBeats.Enqueue("Heart beat received at: " + DateTime.Now);
                heartBeatCount++;
                string js = @"var span = document.getElementById('beatSpan');
                if(span !== null){
                span.parentNode.removeChild(span); 
                }
                var counter = 1;
                span = document.createElement('span');
                span.setAttribute('id', 'beatSpan');
                span.innerHTML = '" + heartBeatCount + @" Heart Beats.<br /> Last heart beat receieved ';

                var childSpan = document.createElement('span');
                childSpan.setAttribute('id', 'count');
                span.appendChild(childSpan);
                if(document.getElementsByTagName('div').length > 0){
                document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(span)
                }
                else{
                document.body.appendChild(span);
                }
                if(timer !== null) clearInterval(timer);
                var timer = setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = ++counter + ' sec ago'}, 1000);";

                m_CurPage.WebView.EvalScript(js);
                break;

            case "notifyErrorInfo":
                m_CurPage.WebView.EvalScript("alert('"+ e.Arguments[0] + "')");
                break;

            case "notifyFlashingCompleted":
                m_CurPage.WebView.EvalScript("alert('Flashing Completed notification received')");
                break;
        }
    }
```

On the front-end I am using javascript. This is how I invoke `eoWebBrowser`:

```
heartbeatInterval = setInterval(function() {
    window.eval(eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", {}));
},5000)
```

This `javascript` function will help me call that `C# function`. I can also see the results on the frontend webpage. Now I am trying to create a log file on javascript side, the function must have the following details:

- look for the textfile
- if file exists append whatever I am sending from `c#` to that text file
- if file doesnt exist create a file and then append what ever the data I am sending from `c#` side

When the pageload is done, the text has to be created and the results from `c# eobrowser` must append to the `JavaScript` created text file. I'm using pure javascript only, no jquery or angular frameworks.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: since the above program works where i can send data from c# to javascript and show it on a webpage. can i do the same where i will get data from c# and instead of displaying on the webpage can i append the data on a textfile.